# How to cut UIView content?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Please help!!! I am using gesture recognizer to move my UIView. During moving I am changing width of my view, but content become out of borders... How to cut content of view? I need only temporary cut it, not remove, because I need then restore content. Does anybody know the solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set [clipsToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) property of your view to YES (either programmatically or in interface builder).

Comment: Great suggestion about either doing it programmatically or in IB

Answer (score 2):

Normally, a subview’s visibile area is not clipped to the bounds of its superview, but in iOS you can use the clipsToBounds property to alter that behavior.

Try setting

```
myView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```